# How to get UIBezierpath using Glyph in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibezierpath, glyph

How can we get `UIBezierPath` from a character using `Glyph` in iOS SDK.

I had gone through [this](https://github.com/ole/Animated-Paths), but It is showing double line and I want only single line..

As I am new in this research..Please help me to solve this problem.. I do not want any code but want to get reference from you..

Actually I want to get `UIBezierPath` describing the shape of each letter of alphabets..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

I happen to have had to do this for a project I am working on, I found this reference very helpful: [Low-level text rendering](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109729/Low-level-text-rendering).

The core code that I used to create a path from a glyph (adjusted for your case):

```
CGGlyph glyph = ...;
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 25, NULL);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGPathRef path = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyph, &transform);
UIBezierPath *bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
CFRelease(font);
```